# How to split Input Text of Map (Hadoop)?

Tags: java, hadoop

I want to know how can I split a input text in map method (Hadoop).

My input file is like :

```html
aaaa
aaaa
aaaa
aaaa
aaaa
```

When I run this code :

```
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
        String[] lines = value.toString().split("\\n");
            paire.set("hi");
            one.set(lines.length);
            context.write(paire,one);
    }
}
```

The output is :

```html
hi 1
hi 1
hi 1
hi 1
hi 1
```

I don't know why lines.length is equal to 1 and not 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are writing length of an array split-en by `\n` which will be always one for provided data. Input for map is always a new line for text data...

***refactor your code:***

```
public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
            //System.out.println("hi " + value.getLength());
            context.write(new Text("hi"), new Text(String.valueOf(value.getLength())));
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! :)